# How to order tuples based on another, referal tuple

Tags: scala

The following `Iterable` can be o size `one`, `two`, or (up to) `three`.

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Iterable[(String, String, String, String, Long)]] = MappedRDD[17] at map at <console>:75
```

The second element of each tuple can have any of the following values: `A`, `B`, `C`. Each of these values can appear (at most) once.

What I would like to do is sort them based on the following order (`B` , `A` , `C`), and then create a string by concatenating the elements of the 3rd place. If the corresponding `tag` is missing then concatenate with a blank space: ``. For example:

this:

```
CompactBuffer((blah,A,val1,blah,blah), (blah,B,val2,blah,blah), (blah,C,val3,blah,blah))
```

should result in:

```
val2,val1,val3
```

this:

```
CompactBuffer((blah,A,val1,blah,blah), (blah,C,val3,blah,blah))
```

should result in:

```
,val1,val3
```

this:

```
CompactBuffer((blah,A,val1,blah,blah), (blah,B,val2,blah,blah))
```

should result in:

```
val2,val1,
```

this:

```
CompactBuffer((blah,B,val2,blah,blah))
```

should result in:

```
val2,,
```

and so on so forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case when `A`, `B` and `C` appear at most once, you could add the corresponding values to a temporary map and retrieve the values from the map in the correct order.

If we use `getOrElse` to get the values from the map, we can specify the empty string as default value. This way we still get the correct result if our `Iterable` doesn't contain all the tuples with `A`, `B` and `C`.

```
type YourTuple = (String, String, String, String, Long)
def orderTuples(order: List[String])(iter: Iterable[YourTuple]) = {
  val orderMap = iter.map { case (_, key, value, _, _) => key -> value }.toMap
  order.map(s => orderMap.getOrElse(s, "")).mkString(",")
}
```

We can use this function as follows :

```
val a = ("blah","A","val1","blah",1L)
val b = ("blah","B","val2","blah",2L)
val c = ("blah","C","val3","blah",3L)

val order = List("B", "A", "C")
val bacOrder = orderTuples(order) _

bacOrder(Iterable(a, b, c))  // String = val2,val1,val3
bacOrder(Iterable(a, c))     // String = ,val1,val3
bacOrder(Iterable(a, b))     // String = val2,val1,
bacOrder(Iterable(b))        // String = val2,,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def orderTuples(xs: Iterable[(String, String, String, String, String)],
                order: (String, String, String) = ("B", "A", "C")) = {

  type T = Iterable[(String, String, String, String, String)]
  type KV = Iterable[(String, String)]

  val ord = List(order._1, order._2, order._3)

  def loop(xs: T, acc: KV, vs: Iterable[String] = ord): KV = xs match {
    case Nil if vs.isEmpty => acc
    case Nil => vs.map((_, ",")) ++: acc
    case x :: xs => loop(xs, List((x._2, x._3)) ++: acc, vs.filterNot(_ == x._2))
  }

  def comp(x: String) = ord.zipWithIndex.toMap.apply(x)

  loop(xs, Nil).toList.sortBy(x => comp(x._1)).map(_._2).mkString(",")
}
```